# Making a random coordinate generator

Tags: python, random, coordinates

This code was originally meant for user input, however I want it to randomly create a polygon rather than manually selecting points myself.
I'll probably make it a for loop, rather than a while loop so you don't need to mention that.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
import random
from random import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), 0, 32)
points = []


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        point1 = randint(0,639)
        point2 = randint(0,479)
        points = (str(randint(0,639)), str(randint(0,479)))

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

        if len(points) >= 3:
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (0,255,0), points)
        for point in points:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,255), point, 5)

            pygame.display.update()
```

What I am attempting to do is to make a coordinate point randomizer.
However, it isn't compatible with this code for some reason. I tried other things as well, and remnants of those attempts may be visible.
The segment I changed goes from the `for event in pygame.event.get`to the `screen.fill((255,255,255))`.
The original code was like this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()

    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        points.append(event.pos)

    screen.fill((255,255,255))
```

When I run the program, I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Documents/it/Python/manual_box drawer.py", line 26, in <module>
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0,0,255), point, 5)
TypeError: must be 2-item sequence, not int
```

error report.

Comment: `point` is an `int`, not a `2-item sequence`... what is confusing about that?

Comment: That much is obvious but (due to severe noobness) I don't fully understand how to make a 2 item sequence. Probably missed something in the reading.

Comment: Just think about what `for point in points` is actually doing. Iterating over a list. And returning a single element because you used `points = ` rather than `points += `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this

```
points = (str(randint(0,639)), str(randint(0,479)))
```

Should be written like so (the extra comma makes a tuple). You need to append to the `points` list rather than re-assign the variable.

```
points.append( (point1, point2,) )
```

Then you can loop over `points` and draw them like you are already trying to do.

Comment: Well apart from using your `for point in points:` suggestion I have implemented your suggestion and it is working.

Comment: Do  you not need that to iterate over the entire list and draw all the points?